# fit over/under dict percentage values to 100%?

Tags: python-2.7

working with python-2.7. I have hundreds of dictionaries and need to force percentages so they add up to 100%. examples below.

```
atest = {'8P00WW': 0.5, '8P00WV': 0.2, '8P032I': 0.2, '8P00C8': 0.1} #total: 1.0
btest = {'8P0D37': 0.3, '8P0B5C': 0.25, '8P0CMG': 0.2}              #total: .75
ctest = {'8P03KK': 0.9, '8P0DVD': 0.4, '8P05JV': 0.05}               #total: 1.35
```

I took a crack at writing a function and it seems to work but is there a better way?

```
def fit2one(dict):
''' return a dictionary where values add up to 1 '''
    output = {}
    for k, v in (dict.items()):
        output[k] = v/sum(dict.values())
    return output
```

idle session using the btest dictionary

```
>>> bresult = fit2one(btest)  
>>> bresult  
{'8P0B5C': 0.3333333333333333, '8P0D37': 0.39999999999999997, '8P0CMG': 0.26666666666666666}     
>>> sum(bresult.values())
1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something essentially same as above, except this updates the dictionary in place and calculates sum once. Saves some memory (no additional dict is defined) and also less expensive than dict(k, v/s). But of course that will only matter for big dictionaries or if you are doing this very often.

```
atest = {'8P00WW': 0.5, '8P00WV': 0.2, '8P032I': 0.2, '8P00C8': 0.1} #total: 1.0
btest = {'8P0D37': 0.3, '8P0B5C': 0.25, '8P0CMG': 0.2}              #total: .75
ctest ={'8P03KK': 0.9, '8P0DVD': 0.4, '8P05JV': 0.05}               #total: 1.35

def fit_to_one(d):
    s = sum(d.values())
    for k,v in d.items():
        d[k] = v/s

    return d

print fit_to_one(atest)
print fit_to_one(btest)
print fit_to_one(ctest)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the way to do it, giving them equivalent proportional weightings. There are some minor changes that might make this more efficient:

```
def fit2one(d):
    s = sum(d.values())
    return dict((k, v/s) for k, v in d.items())
```

All that really does is lift the `sum` out of the loop, and this will only really matter for large `dict`s.